# multiple controls like button and text boxes in dropdown list using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdownbox

I have two requirements in my project. First, when I click on button, a `div` should be visible and invisible. I have achieved that using JQuery, as shown in this link.[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/excfm2p2/1/)

Now second requirement is, I'm opening a `div` in first case, now I have to open same box but as a dropdown list. That means if I click on dropdown `Filter`, this box given in link should open, and it should overlay if something under it, like in my case I have grid. So dropdown should overlay this grid but not replace it. I have googled it but didn't find any appropriate solution. I just need that control which will do the magic. Not whole code.

if any clarification needed. please comment. thanks.

Comment: if you can vote down, then plz give reason and or solution too.

Comment: You will add a dropdown in the grid box? and you want to appear it top of all other things?
And I have not voted down. :)

Comment: i just want that box in dropdown list. simple

Comment: that box which appears on clicking Filter button will appear in a dropdown?? AND the Filter will appear as a dropdown list?? But I can't see the dropdown in your Fiddle, can you please add it or if you have added it your project and the grid box is below the dropdown then try setting in the css `z-index: 9999` for the grid box.

Comment: no i have not added dropdown in fiddle. in my fiddle, box is `div`, now take a scene, i have button and just its below, there is a textbox. now in my fiddle, if i click this button, the box will appear and textbox which is below button will move down

Comment: but i dont want that. i want to overlay this box on textbox.

Comment: okay got it, I just added a text box below filter button in your fiddle, and I saw the text box is shifting down when the grid box appears. you don't want that shift, you want the textbox to remain there and the gridbox to appear above it.

Comment: exactly.. i dont have any idea how to achieve it

Comment: see my answer, posting it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commented out the code which I have added. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/excfm2p2/2/).
First you need to set `position: absolute` then add the JS to position the dropdown below the button.

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $('#btn').live('click', function (event)
        {

            $('#div1').toggle('show');

        });
        // added the following script
        var offH = $('#btn').outerHeight();
        var offT = $('#btn').offset().top + offH;
        var offL = $('#btn').offset().left;
        $('#div1').css('top', offT+"px").css('left', offL+"px");
    });
```

CSS

```
   #div1{
       display:none;
       position: absolute;     /* ADDED THIS LINE */
   }
```